# Why do phone makers not let me uninstall their pre-bundled apps?

Tags: applications

When I got my most recent phone, a Samsung Galaxy S5, it came with all sorts of apps that I never touch. "Kids Mode", "Samsung Health", "Samsung Remote", and a host of other apps that I haven't used and will never use.

I understand why these come preinstalled. It's offering the option to use them, and I'm sure some users will find it convenient to have suggested uses for their phone.

What I don't understand is why I can't get rid of them. What is the value for anyone in forcing me to keep applications I will never use?

Bonus question: Can I get rid of them? My phone is rooted.

Comment: The technical reason is because built in apps are installed in the system partition which is mounted read only, to protect it from factory reset. The question you should ask is why these bloat wares have been installed in the system partition in the first place. If you decide to remove a bundled app and later decide to sell the device, take care that a factory reset won't be sufficient to restore the device to the original state.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I get rid of them?

Sure! If you wanna go straight ahead then try an app like [System app uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljmobile.system.app&hl=en) to remove system apps including the bloatware. Remember to remove with utmost caution since a critical file once removed may render the Android unusable at best.

See [Titanium Backup](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb) too which can take backup and remove junk from Android.

To counter the above issue of unusable system, I advise installing a custom Recovery and then taking a Nandroid Backup (save it to external storage) to be at safe side if things go south.

> Why do phone makers not let me uninstall their pre-bundled apps?

I don't think you'll ever hear an official announcement as a reason but my guess is they want business, and their apps (bloatware for us) helps in doing that by maintaining a user base through restricting the freedom to tweak the system.

> What is the value for anyone in forcing me to keep applications I will never use?

This anyone is your OEM which harness lot of things from these forced apps, as you said *"I'm sure some users will find it convenient to have suggested uses for their phone."*

Note that some OEMs allow you to root your device without voiding the warranty, so technically, they are not forcing but just trying different techniques to maintain their business.

> Why I can't get rid of them[?]

Most of the time, you can get rid of them by having root access but it may result in dire consequences. One such is, your warranty may be void by rooting your device if your OEM has such policy.

**Edit:** As per [this article](https://fsfe.org/freesoftware/legal/flashingdevices.en.html) suggested by [Bowdzone](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/113385/bowdzone), rooting your device won't void the warranty of a consumer from EU, since the consumer is protected by **statutory warranty** (irrespective of your OEM's policies).

<sub>Over and all, except the first and last part the rest is plain opinion.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Just navigate to system/app and delete any bloatware you want. Be careful that you don't delete anything that is crucial to the functioning of the system.

Comment: For most, if not all, of the bloatware, the option to uninstall is greyed out.

Comment: @Questioner, no, I meant, use a file manager to navigate to /system/app, where most the system apps are located. Simply deleting their .apk's, and restarting your phone should make the bloatware go away. You could always copy these files, before deleting, to back-up them, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: simplest way possible. yeah.