# Where is data of Google Play Services located in device? Can I safely delete it?

Tags: google-play-services, app-data

Just noticed that data in internal storage for Google Play Services app grew above 100Mib, so this app is officially a space hog now.

So my questions are:

1. What is the exact location for Google Play Services data? (for backing up)
2. Can I safely delete Google Play Services data and let the app recreate it?
3. What might I lose if I delete Google Play Services data unsafely?

Comment: Hi! I reflected in the title some points you raised, and removed some tags since they weren't specific to the question. I hope that's OK!

Comment: @Firelord, I'm rather new here, so that's OK for me. I've got **quality solution** for my question after all (thanks again!). I've made that tag soup merely because Play Services attracted my attention as space-hog, my 4.2.2 device has only 1Gb of internal storage, so I'm always worrying about free space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is exact location for Google Play Services data?

Package name of Google Play Services is [`com.google.android.gms`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms).

Default data directory of apps is under `/data/data`, and for Play Services, it is `/data/data/com.google.android.gms`.

Note that you can't simply copy-paste it into anywhere. To peek into data directory of an app you would need root access. Fortunately, for non-root devices, Play Services allows its backup using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb).

After installing ADB, enter this command in a shell:

```
adb backup -apk com.google.android.gms
```

This will save the backup in the file `backup.ab` located in the current directory.

To restore that backup, enter this command from the same *current* directory:

```
adb restore backup.ab
```

> Can I safely delete Google Play Services data and let app recreate it?

By safely, if you mean clearing data from **Settings → Apps→ Downloaded → Google Play Services**, then you're good to go.

In Android 4.4.2 and 5.0.2, you don't get the straight option named **Clear Data**. Instead you get **Manage space**. Follow the screenshots:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; hover to know details)</sub>

[image: IMG: 1] [image: IMG: 2] [image: IMG: 3]

However, in Android 4.2.1, there was no **Manage Space** but **Clear Data**. Perhaps, the former option is Android version specific and not app specific.

Doing `adb shell pm clear com.google.android.gms` is also safe, at least, my Play Store, and Gmail (both ridiculously dependent on Play Services) worked fine after executing both steps independently.

The data recreated too.

> What I might lose if I delete Google Play Services data unsafely?

I don't know what unsafely would mean here other than purging the app directory of Play Services without uninstalling it, so I can't comment on it.

Anyhow, the front-end of Play Services is named **Google Settings**, [the core of Google Apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114353/96277), whose icon you would see in your app drawer. Simply open it, and the entries you would see  are possibly responsible for the data collection of Play Services. And as I said above, the dependent apps worked fine without a hitch, so this app's data isn't something I would worry about. Your case may vary, so dig deeper into this app's GUI.

Comment: Neat answer, thanks! And *whoa*, in your case Google Play Services isn't space-greedy at all.

Comment: Perhaps that's because I don't use much of it other than sometimes downloading an app from Play Store, or using Gmail. In my other devices, the data specifically rose up to 50MB. Yours is a special case since both data and APK would be taking ~200MB of internal storage.

Comment: While it's not the same thing, I think I need to put this as precaution due to its similarity: [PSA: **Do not clear data for *Google Service Framework*** (Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1r1n5z/psa_do_not_clear_data_for_google_service_framework/)