# whathappens if i hit the manage space button in google play services

Tags: applications

what happens when I hit manage space button in google play services im trying to free storage space so I can download an app

Comment: See the screenshots here: [Where is data of Google Play Services located in device? Can I safely delete it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/117632)

Comment: Don't worry- pressing the "Manage storage" button won't break you phone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens when you press the "Manage storage" button in Google Play Services through App Management:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Tapping any of the apps on the "Search Data" page just goes to that app's "manage" page.