# Should I clear cache for Google Play Services or will an app misbehave?

Tags: google-play-services

I need more space and I saw somewhere that I can clear the cache for Google Play Services but I'm not sure if something will go wrong

Help please!

Comment: You can go ahead. Cache doesn't contain critical data. Related: [Where is data of Google Play Services located in device? Can I safely delete it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/117582)

Comment: Should you ? Not necessarily. But it won't do any harm.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). Isn't your question rather "how to gain more space"? Better ask the real question than how to get your supposed solution to work. There might be (and in this case are) better solutions available – see e.g. our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info).

Answer (score 1):

Clearing cache for an app will never delete any important information, only data held to make loading images etc faster. Data, however, is often used to store important information.

If the app is using too much data, I would say that there probably isn't much harm in clearing it, but if the app doesn't store much data, there isn't much point.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to clear cache, but make sure you don't clear data as it will remove you Google account and you will have to login again.

Answer (score 0):

I've  clear cache on Play Store many times as well as clear cache/clear data which then routes me to a manage space button and/or a page with my multiple Google apps to manage spaces of app(s) of my choice that I'm trying to clear. I usually don't have to sign in again. Maybe because of dual sign ins on various Google apps however clearing data could very well reset your Google Play Store settings back to default; enter dreaded auto updates and auto permissions and auto storage/memory hogger upper